# Why does bind() work so inconsistently in Vue template event handlers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When experimenting with a bit of fancy syntax in my templates today I came across a confusing behaviour of the `bind()` function in Vue event handlers.

Ignoring any possibly bad practices and the fact that the bind is completely pointless here, please look at the following 2 code samples.

1.

```html
<template>
  <button @click="(() => console.log('this gets logged')).bind()"></button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    console: () => console,
  },
}
</script>
```

2. 

```html
<template>
  <button @click="myFunc.bind()"></button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    myFunc () { console.log("this doesn't get logged") }
  }
}
</script>
```

Code sample 1 properly logs an output to the console when clicking the button, but for some reason sample 2 doesn't log anything. Why?

Answer (score -1):

`myFunc.bind()` in Sample 2 returns the reference to new function, but does not call it.

To make it work as expected, `myFunc.bind()()` is required.

```
<template>
  <button @click="myFunc.bind()()"></button>
</template>
```

- looks weired, but works

Comment: Sample 1 doesn't call it either.

Comment: `(() => console.log('this gets logged')).bind()` in sample 1 also returns a reference to a new function and doesn't call it, yet it works.

Comment: `bind()` does not any effect for console.log. console.log works without `bind()`. With enclosing outer parenthesis `(` function `)`, inner fuction is called.

Comment: A function isn't called by enclosing it in parentheses.